# Rule based labeling in rule based styles

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I have got a layer with distance vectors between polygons. This layer has a rule based style where I can check each polygon to show only the vectors with contact to the polygon. Each vector has as an attribute the start and the endpoint (name of polygon)

I want to add a rule based labeling which should depend on the chosen stylename. Is there a function like "$get_active_stylename" which can be used as a variable?

The layerstyle Looks like this

[image]

There are some sub rules.

[image]

The polygons are buildings. So I want to chose building 86 and the label hase to be rulebased to building 86. The problem is that building 86 can be the start or the end of the vector.

QGIS 2.14

Comment: can u share what u did so far to make things a bit more clear ?

Comment: I edit my question. Hope it makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: If I understand what you're going for, you could achieve the same end by duplicating the rules from Style into Labels. Perhaps this could be done by opening the QGIS file in a text editor and copying and pasting the rules. Just a thought. Backup your QGIS file before attempting.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the colour the feature is styled with if that's any help?

```
CASE WHEN  @symbol_color = '#ffffff'
THEN 'label for symbology 1'
ELSE 'label for symbology 2'
END
```